Conditionally cancel() Flux and preserve value causing cancel
I have following Reactive Flux stream in Java,
Flux.just(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5)
   .flatMapSequentially(/* process elements */)
   .scan(new Accumulator(null, 0), (element, total) -> new Accumulator(element, element.children.size + total))
   .takeWhile(/* conditionally process till for example e3, need accumulator value here */)
   .map(/* post processing */)

record Accumulator(Element element, int total) {}

in takeWhile the cancel happens conditionally at element e3, and once cancelled, the value will not be available in subsequent .map(), and stream returns with e1, e2 only, But I need e3 element also along with e1, e2.
How can I preserve e3 conditionally?

You can use takeUntil instead:

This includes the matching data (unlike takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate<? super T>)).

Example:
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

public class TakeUntilTest {

    @Test
    public void takeUntilIncludesStopElement() {
        var datasStream = Flux.range(1, 10)
                // Stop when we encounter value 3
                .takeUntil(i -> i.equals(3));
        StepVerifier.create(datasStream)
                // verify resulting flow include stop value
                .expectNext(1, 2, 3)
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}


Thanks @amanin, Yes I was able to solve it using takeUntil
